# User page layout borked in Firefox?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, users

Maybe it's just me, but this is what the user page looks like in Firefox (but not in IE or Chrome).
[image: Random user]

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you're showing (using Firefox 15.0.1) - what version of Firefox are you seeing this in?

Comment: @RowlandShaw, same as you. I'll try on another PC and report back.

Comment: @RowlandShaw, it was an add-on

Comment: This user page looks familiar somehow. I can't quite place it....

Answer (score 1):

OK, it was an add-on:

[Stack Exchange Favorite Users](http://michalbures.com/projects/stack-exchange-favorite-users/)

Strange, because I haven't observed this on any other SE sites...

Comment: It's a combination of the styling + that add=on...but unfortunately we can't reasonably account for third party extensions and what they'll do to the UI.  I would contact the author though, this is certainly resolvable on their end.